# PHP: Mysql rollback multiple query (done via ajax) if user not pressed submit button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have one page, within this page insert/update/delete action performed via ajax jQuery.

if user don't press submit button or press cancel button than roll-back all changes/query performed via ajax.
not possible with temporary table because there are lots of data.

Kindly suggest me proper way to do that.

Comment: Temporary table is not bad, even with lots of data if they are used properly. You can also work with session. Store your data in the user's session and once your form has been submitted, update your tables.

Comment: I would look at storing it in session my self just as kevin said. I am not sure about temp tables and the restrictions with them.

Comment: Session is your only option.  After adding ajax data, you have 3 possible outcomes, submit click, cancel click, page abandonment.  There is no way to handle #3 using anything but sessions.

Comment: I will try to use session or temporary table. thanks for responses.

Comment: @KevinLabécot, but its complicated to manage edit/update records because first time need to fetch data from table and than user performed action on that i want to manage second time user actions.

Comment: Of course but sometime best way is complicated ;) Load your data into a temp table, work with it and then load you processed data into the original table.

Comment: @KevinLabécot i think about that but i was thinking there is any other best way to resolve this. but Thank you for your suggestions I will use Temp table.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness yes right #3 is only possible in session. i am confused to use temporary table or session which one is best and how to handle delete/edited data, i am using kendo ui grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [MySQL Transactions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx) and specifically the ROLLBACK statement if your database is InnoDB. It will do your job.

If you put the query in a transaction, you can commit it if submit button is pushed or rollback it in an other case.

Comment: Transactions are not going to work for this use case.  He said the data was added via ajax calls.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness yes right I tried Transactions and Roll-back.

Comment: Yes you are right never used 'em over ajax and thought i would work

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the Page Leave event. And then delete what you want.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

Comment: This assumes browsers never crash.

Comment: Wow... this is a very bad way do to that. Browser can crash, onbeforeunload is not universal...

Comment: In the last step, pull flag at the end of the transaction. Just ignore the records without last step flag(true).